# How to make the re.sub() method replace a word only if this word is NOT preceded by a number \d?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re

input_str = "esta a mil o a 25 mil 500 millas de la ciudad de milan" #Example 1
input_str = "mil o mas para pasar! y tu tienes menos de mil" #Example 2
input_str = "hace casi mil o 2mil anos aparecio un fenomeno legendario tan solo a millas de aqui" #Example 3
```

How do I make it do the replacement if the word `"mil"` is NOT preceded by a number `\d`?

```py
input_str = re.sub(r"\d[\s|]*(?:mil)", " 1 mil" , input_str)
```

Output for this 3 examples that I need:

```py
"esta a 1 mil o a 25 mil 500 millas de la ciudad de milan" # for Example 1

"1 mil o mas para pasar! y tu tienes menos de 1 mil" # for Example 2

"hace casi 1 mil o 2mil anos aparecio un fenomeno legendario tan solo a millas de aqui" # for Example 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the regex would be:

- [`(?<!\d\s)(?<!\d)(mil)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/nOXv81/1)

Meaning that you want to capture `mil` if the character before it is not a number, `\d`, or a number then a space, `\d\s`. I'm using two negative lookbehinds since python doesn't support a variable length lookbehind.

[image]

Comment: This will not work for example 1, as it replaces mil in 25 mil, which was not suppose to happen. It replaces 25 mil to 251 mil.

Comment: mmm... is there any way to incorporate the possible space(or spaces) in the middle? `[\s|]*` . Since you should avoid cases like  `"17 mil" `,  `"6        mil" `, or  `"17mil" `

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez oh I see, so it could have spaces and actually multiple digits too then. Sure let me re-try.

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez see updated answer please.

Comment: @David542 Really thanks for the help! The `<!` is a kind of equivalent (in regex) of the statement `if not`?